# Debian squeeze and setting ulimit

Tags: debian, ulimit

All

I want to permanently set the core file size to unlimited.
Reading about it, the suggestion is to modify the /etc/security/limits.conf. 
I have done so with the following line:

- soft    core            10000
  root            hard    core            10000

I reboot after the change and I issue ulimit -a and core is still set to 0.
Can not understand why the setting is not working. What can be overwriting it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
*               soft    nofile          10000
*               hard    nofile          10000
```

and add this line to `.profile` file, f.e. for `root` in `/root/.profile`

```
ulimit -c 10000
```

or for all users in `/etc/profile`.

Remember: for remote users: `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and for su `/etc/pam.d/su`

```
session    required     /lib/security/pam_limits.so
```

Comment: A typo I'm sure, but he wants core file size limit changed (core), whereas you are changing the number of open files limit (nofile) in your suggestion for limits.conf

Comment: Do i have to reboot or restart the services using the configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

use this command

```
ulimit -SHn 65535
```

Comment: simple, why are all the other answers so much more complicated?

Comment: this is not persistent after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing docker-compose up and have issue

Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 99: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

Please restart your docker service as
sudo service docker restart